# swift - how to filtering my custom class?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I was make class with string, url and int values and make channel array
but I can't make a good filtering for my channel array

this is my class:

```
class Channel {
    var name: String
    var url: URL
    var icon: URL?
    var priority: Int

    init(name:String, url:URL, icon:URL?, priority:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.icon = icon
        self.priority = priority
    }
}
```

I was trying this function but it' doesn't worked!

```
public var channels: [Channel] = []
    var filteredData = [Channel]()
    var searching = false
...

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return filteredData.count
        }
        return channels.count

    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let channel = channels[indexPath.item] as Channel? {
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {

                if searching {
                    cell.name.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].name
                    print("fil \(filteredData[indexPath.row].name)")
                } else {
                    cell.name.text = channel.name
                    print("not \(channel.name)")

                }


                if let iconUrl = channel.icon {
                    cell.icon.cacheSetImageFromURL(iconUrl)
                } else {
                    cell.icon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tv1600")
                }
                return cell
            }
        }

        return UICollectionViewCell()

    }

...

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
            searching = false
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }else{
            print("searching")
            searching = true

            filteredData = channels.filter({$0.name.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})

            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

My Expected results show the filtered array with the existing contents in my CollctionView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `cellForItemAt` as below,

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let channel = self.searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : channels[indexPath.item]
        cell.name.text = channel.name
        print("fil \(channel.name)")

        if let iconUrl = channel.icon {
            cell.icon.cacheSetImageFromURL(iconUrl)
        } else {
            cell.icon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tv1600")
        }
        return cell
  }
```

This line(`if let channel = channels[indexPath.item] as Channel? {`) is causing the issue where you are always taking `channel` object from the non-filtered array that has all the elements even during searching. So you should take the `channel` object from the corresponding `array` as above to properly show the `results`.

Comment: thanks, but still my search function doesn't working.

Comment: Verify your `filteredData` list has the correct results.